# absolute path in HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, html, path

I'm trying to build a HTML template with a small javascript code. Here is the stuff... At the root, I built two files : 
 
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <title>HTML Template</title>
  <!-- Header initialized with /header-footer.js -->

</head>
<body>

  <footer>
    <!-- Footer initialized with /header-footer.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/headerfooter.js"></script>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

headerfooter.js

```
(function () {

    /*************** HEADER *****************/
    const headerBeforeAppend = document.querySelector('head')

    document.querySelector('head').innerHTML = `
      ${headerBeforeAppend.innerHTML}

      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

      <!-- CSS -->
      <!-- Google fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Bootstrap, Materialize, etc... you see the idea -->

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <!-- Fontawesome -->
      <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/45d80bbe59.js"></script>
      <!-- jQuery, Bootstrap scripts, etc... you see the idea -->
    `

    /*************** FOOTER *****************/

    const footerBeforeAppend = document.querySelector('footer')

    document.querySelector('footer').innerHTML = `
      ${footerBeforeAppend.innerHTML}

      <!-- JQuery (for Bootstrap) -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap CDN v4 alpha-->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    `

    })()
```

The idea is, when I load the index.html in a browser, to have the headerfooter.js script to write my `<head>` section and my `<footer>` section with the `<links>` and `<script>` I need.

It's actually working perfectly when, for the script, the code I write is the relative path to the script : `<script type="text/javascript" src="headerfooter.js"></script>`, but it's not working with the absolute path to the root: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/headerfooter.js"></script>`.
This is a problem, because I would like this to be a template, so that I include this script in every html page I will create in my web folder without having to re-write the path everytime. Did I make a mistake somewhere ? 
(PS: is it a bad practice trying to build a template like that ?)

Comment: Where is the script relative to your pages? Will it always be the same? If not you should use an `absolute` path like: `http://www.example.com/example.js` - `/headerfooter.js` is a relative path...

Comment: Is the file actually hosted in an absolute path?  If you browse to `/headerfooter.js`, do you get javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you run your page will matter.

If you're trying to run it with the `file://` protocol (by just opening `index.html`), an absolute path won't resolve correctly. You'll want to somehow run an local server (there are dozens of ways to do this, depending what all you're using, too large a scope for this question).

If you are running some kind of local server (i.e., `http://localhost`), then try opening the file directly with `http://localhost/headerfooter.js`. If that doesn't work, your file isn't quite where you think it is.