# using a js script to generate <head> and <footer>

Tags: javascript, html, templates

When we have always the same `<links>`or `<script>`to load in the `<head>`or `<footer>`of all the HTML file of our website, it is really painful to copy/paste in each and every page of the web folder, especially when we have to modify them.
I [wrote a JavaScript script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776922/absolute-path-in-html-is-not-working/46777004#46777004) in order to load the same content in every HTML page: I wrote the content in the script (using ES6) and load the content everywhere I call the script.
Is it a good practice or a very bad one?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use php or another language to do it with file inclusion?

Answer (score 2):

Use a framework e.g., [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Cosign using a framework; Webpack is also a great alternative to bundle your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

What you need would be easily done in PHP. All you'd need is one footer and one header file, that would be used as templates and you would just use PHP tags to include the header and footer where needed, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'header.php';?>


<?php include 'footer.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you would rather go with JavaScript entirely you could use Node, with let's say, Express for the back-end, you would use  [EJS includes](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) for the header and footer.

Comment: I'm talking more about the `<head>` than the `<header>`. But thanks for the advice, though my target is to not use PHP if possible :)

Comment: That go with the JavaScript route all of the stuff that goes into the head of the HTML file would go in the header template in any scenario. If you need more info on JavaScript templating, check out this article: http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396